# Including a file that includes another file

Tags: php

Folder Structure

- root

  - inc/

    - db.php
    - session.php
    - db.php
    - init.php
  - lib/

    - Twig/
- init.php

login.php file

```
<?php
include 'inc/init.php';
```

init.php

```
<?php
include 'session.php';

$config = include 'config.php';
include 'db.php';

require_once '/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

What I'm so confused about is the fact that the Twig library gets included. Shouldn't I need to back a folder ../ ? But that is giving me an error, and I simply don't understand why.

Comment: If you read the last sentences, you obviously understand there is no error but a missunderstand why it works like it does.

Comment: Since `init.php` file is already in the `root` directory ( which I guess is your main directory ) you don't need to back anywhere. You are at the most top level of your directory structure. If you are in browser at blank page how would you go back from there? Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute path for Twig, this is why it is included. If you want to include it from your `init.php` file  using relative path, then it should be like this:

```
require_once './lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

What the PHP include statement does, is that it takes the file you include and dump everything in the including file. So if you include a file in the init.php in the root folder all includes are relative to the root.

To grasp that. throw some statements in your inclusion files like `printf("I am in init.db, the current folder is %s", getcwd());` that will help you to understand what the current directory is when the files are included and you can modify your includes accordingly.